# How adjust the anchor point or start point from the first condition to the latest condition

Tags: pine-script

My goal is to create a script that starts the Avwap on the latest condition
rather than how it is now on the first condition ...

I am using the ema 15 and ema 30 cross to start the condition

working with time sure is something

```
        //@version=4
        // MileStone 13.2
        study("Avwap Condition", overlay=true)

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        //----Ema condition trigger
        ema1=ema(close,15)
        ema2=ema(close,30)
        cond01 = cross(ema1,ema2)

        plot(ema1, color=#ffffff)
        plot(ema2, color=#ffff00)

//---- Store Time Value :)
        var int timecond = na

        if cond01
            if na(timecond)
                timecond := time
        
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

//---- src 
        src = high

//---- Timestamp 
        timediff = timecond

        YearCTD = year(timediff)
        monthCTD = month(timediff)
        dateCTD = dayofmonth(timediff)
        hourCTD = hour(timediff)
        secondCTD = second(timediff)

        momentCTD = timestamp(YearCTD, monthCTD, dateCTD, hourCTD, secondCTD)

//---- Start time ???
        startCTD = time >= momentCTD and time[1] < momentCTD

//---- Avwap math stuff 
        sumSrcCTD = src * volume
        sumVolCTD = volume
        sumSrcCTD := startCTD ? sumSrcCTD : sumSrcCTD + sumSrcCTD[1]
        sumVolCTD := startCTD ? sumVolCTD : sumVolCTD + sumVolCTD[1]
        Avwap= sumSrcCTD / sumVolCTD

//---- plotting stuff 
        plot(Avwap, title="CTD_VWAP", color=color.blue)
        plot(momentCTD, color=#ff0000)
```

new version
results in red vertical lines where I want the script to start
but the Avwap indicator or part of the script is not beginning ...

```
//@version=4
study("Avwap Condition", overlay=true)

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

//the actual function
f_barssince(_cond, _count) => _barssince=bar_index-valuewhen(_cond, bar_index, _count)

//----Ema's
input=input(0, "Nth Occurrence (zero is the most recent occurrence)", minval=0)
ema1=ema(close,15)
ema2=ema(close,30)

//----Ema condition trigger
condition = cross(ema1,ema2)

//Plot Ema's
//plot(f_barssince(condition, input), color=color.red)
plot(ema1, color=#ffffff)
plot(ema2, color=#ffff00)

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

//---- time now offset by bar count since condition 

Rtime = time - time[f_barssince(condition, input)]

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

//---- Store Time Value :)
//var int timecond = na

//if cond01
    //if na(timecond)
        //timecond := time
    
//if cond01            
    //if int(timecond)
        //timecond := time
        
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

//---- Timestamp 
//timediff = timecond
timediff = Rtime

YearCTD = year(timediff)
monthCTD = month(timediff)
dateCTD = dayofmonth(timediff)
hourCTD = hour(timediff)
secondCTD = second(timediff)

momentCTD = timestamp(YearCTD, monthCTD, dateCTD, hourCTD, secondCTD)

//---- Start time ???
startCTD = time >= momentCTD and time[1] < momentCTD 
//startCTD = time == momentCTD  

//---- Avwap math stuff 

//---- src 
src = high
sumSrcCTD = src * volume
sumVolCTD = volume
sumSrcCTD := startCTD ? sumSrcCTD : sumSrcCTD + sumSrcCTD[1]
sumVolCTD := startCTD ? sumVolCTD : sumVolCTD + sumVolCTD[1]
Avwap = sumSrcCTD / sumVolCTD

//---- plotting stuff 
plot(Avwap, title="CTD_VWAP", color=color.blue)
plot(momentCTD, color=#ff0000)

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

or

```
//@version=4
study("Avwap Condition", overlay=true)

startBar = input(10)

startCTD = startBar == bar_index

//---- src
src = high
//---- Avwap math stuff 
sumSrcCTD = src * volume
sumVolCTD = volume
sumSrcCTD := startCTD ? sumSrcCTD : sumSrcCTD + sumSrcCTD[1]
sumVolCTD := startCTD ? sumVolCTD : sumVolCTD + sumVolCTD[1]
Avwap= sumSrcCTD / sumVolCTD

//---- plotting stuff 
plot(Avwap, title="CTD_VWAP", color=color.blue)

//------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: I believe that if i incorporate either of these two functions I will get the result I am looking for 

https://www.tradingview.com/script/Qw6Amzk3-barssince-Built-in-Replacement-with-2nd-Occurrence-Parameter/#tc4057646

https://www.tradingview.com/script/lfp742sn-Nth-Occurrence-Custom-barssince-Function-by-Cryptorhythms-CR/

Comment: My next plan is to 
    Count Bars since the latest condition 
        Then I will offset a timestamp set to the current time by the bar count

Comment: Just to be clear I am trying to get the Avwap to start on the latest condition 
not the the first :)

Comment: could some one help me to turn the current time frame 
is that the resolution ? into a number 
and multiply it by a bar count ? 
to get time since ?

Comment: Does anyone know how to turn bars since into seconds minuets or hours ?